# Array Printing Segfault

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have the following code, the code compiles and runs if I don't have try to print the array I'm generating, but segfault the second I try to print the array. I'm very confused as to what is going wrong? I'm using the basic valgrind tool on mac which tells me I"m trying to access an unmapped region of memory. The problem also happens if I try to use printf("%f \n", data[i]);

```
#define matA_W 1024
#define matA_H 1024

void  genMatrix(float* data, int size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    data[i] = float (rand() /RAND_MAX);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
  }

}


int main() {
  srand(2006)
  unsigned int size_A = matA_W * matA_H;
  unsigned int memA = sizeof(float) * size_A;
  float* matA = (float*) malloc(memA);

  std::cout << size_A << std::endl;
  std::cout << memA << std::endl;

  genMatrix(matA,size_A);

  return 0;


}
```

Comment: Start learning the right tools of the trade so you can debug this yourself: Valgrind, asan, tsan...

Comment: I'm currently using Valgrind and can pin point the error to an array access that's out of bounds, I just fail to understand why!

Comment: BTW change to `data[i] = (float) rand() / RAND_MAX;`, `srand(2006);`

Comment: OK - if you know that the array access is out of bounds, you need to check that your expectation of the array size is correct -- which is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

`memA` should be `size_A` in your `genMarix` call.